# Функция не видит запись в бд

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

```
def set_sid():
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT rowid FROM segments")
data=cursor.fetchall()
if len(data) != 0:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor = cursor.execute("SELECT max(id) FROM segments")
    max_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    max_id = max_id + 1
    return max_id
else:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO segments VALUES('1', \'{0}\', \'{1}\')".format(get_last_url(),get_last_url_id()))
    conn.commit()
```

Функция проходит цикл для нескольких записей, если отрабатывает `else`, то на втором проходе цикла получаю **sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch** хотя сама запись в бд появилась и при повторном запуске все работает.

Подскажите где неправ. Пардон за индусский код - учусь как могу.

Функцию выше вызываю здесь.

```
def write_url():
if i != 'http://кто.рф/':
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO urls VALUES (\'{0}\', \'{1}\', \'{2}\', '1', '1', \'{3}\', '0', '0')".format(set_id(),i,get_title(),dt_to_filetime(dt)))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO segments VALUES(\'{0}\', \'{1}\', \'{2}\')".format(set_sid(),get_last_url(),get_last_url_id()))
    conn.commit()
else:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO urls VALUES (\'{0}\', \'{1}\', \'{2}\', '1', '1', \'{3}\', '0', '0')".format(set_id(),i,kirurl(),dt_to_filetime(dt)))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO segments VALUES(\'{0}\', \'{1}\', \'{2}\')".format(set_sid(),get_last_url(),get_last_url_id()))
    conn.commit()
```

Цикл:

```
for i in NTV:
    write_url()
```

Comment: А чем плох автоинкремент? и на чём именно падает? На инкременте max_id ? Может стоит его попробывать к инту привести?

Comment: @Чад C Автоинкрементом тоже самое. max_id к инту привожу - не помогло. Прога обещала быть несложной, дебаггер не ставил - пожалуй займусь.

Comment: А если убрать кавычки в инсерте у 1 ?

Comment: @Чад Тоже мимо. Может я проверку на наличие записи как-то не так делаю. Я уже все обугуглил, никак разобраться с этой ошибкой не могу. По другим столбцам проверял, в принципе ничего не изменилось.

Comment: А Вы можете так же привести код из которого вызывается этот?

Comment: @Чад поправил описание

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка `sqlite3.IntegrityError: datatype mismatch` - весьма красноречиво говорит, что запрос INSERT некорректен.

Не надо никогда спешить инсертить в базу динамическое *неизвестно что*, получившеся в результате конкатенации строк. Надо просто вывести это на экран и разобраться что в запросе не так. То есть `cursor.execute` просто заменить на `print` для того, чтобы получить те инсерты, которые ты пытаешься записать в базу.

Тогда будет видна причина ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо! наконец-то - я переосмыслил сущность бытия и все заработало. Проблема действильно была в инсерте.

Comment: рад был помочь.